# Implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable, webservicehost

I have a following class:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   private WebServiceHost m_WebServiceHost;
   // Members
   public void Dispose()
   {
            m_WebServiceHost // how do I dispose this object?
   }
}
```

`WebServiceHost` implements `IDisposable`, but it has no `Dispose` method.

How do I implement `Dispose()`?

Comment: `IDisposable` need to be implemented only if there is any `Disposable` contents exists.

Comment: m_WebServiceHost = null;  Let the GC handle it?

Answer (score 3):

Given that it uses [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx), it's not clear to me that they want you to, but you can:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   private WebServiceHost m_WebServiceHost;
   // Members
   public void Dispose()
   {
            ((IDisposable)m_WebServiceHost).Dispose();
   }
}
```

I would *guess* that they'd prefer you just to call `Close()` on it, but I can't back that up from documentation yet.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   private WebServiceHost m_WebServiceHost;

   // Often you have to override Dispose method 
   protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
     if (disposing) {
       // It looks that WebServiceHost implements IDisposable explicitly
       IDisposable disp = m_WebServiceHost as IDisposable;

       if (!Object.RefrenceEquals(null, disp))
         disp.Dispose();

       // May be useful when debugging
       disp = null;       
     }
   }

   // Members
   public void Dispose()
   {
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: you should add a destructor which calls `Dispose(false);`

Comment: This is the correct answer, but explain why you use the Dispose pattern.

Comment: `disp = null;` seems redundant.

Comment: @thefiloe Not really required.

Comment: well. It is the official and recommended implementation. Just saying.

Comment: @thefiloe Only when you have unmanaged memory it is required, else say no to it.

Comment: Well. For that case, you even don't need the `Dispose(bool)` method

Comment: @thefiloe: You'd rather have Dispose(bool) if you want to derived (from MyClass) class